Attempt to index nil with position drops
The error:

ReplicatedStorage.Modules.Drops:35: attempt to index nil with 'Position'

The line:
if (Character.PrimaryPart.Position - Drop.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude < 10 and Drop.CanCollect.Value == true then

so this is the problem  and since there is 2 positions i do not know with witch one is the issue.
i tried changing the name of the drop  model and doing something with primary part and i tried to find if i made a typo anywhere but not that i can see.  

to use Drop.PrimaryPart you have to actually set the primary part before that else the engine wouldn't know what the primary part is. https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Model#PrimaryPart

Hi. Please to not add error messages and code as screenshots. This makes it hard to search questions and leads to down-votes/closes-votes.


Attempt to index nil with position drops

I am not sure how you get from the actual error message to this title.
The error tells you that in line 35 you'r indexing a nil value with 'Position'.
This means that you should look for something.Position, something:Position( or something["Position"] in that line.
And you'll find that indexing of something which in your case is either Character.PrimaryPart.Position or Drop.PrimaryPart.Position.
In order to find out which of both is nil, in case it is not obvious from the code you can usually just print(Character.PrimaryPart) and print(Drop.PrimaryPart).
If you get a value form somewhere that can be nil you should check if it is nil befor you do anything with it.
